# NSURLErrorDomain error code 1002 description

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to **iOS** development. I am trying to load a **JSON**, here's my function:

```
func loadmyJSON (urlPath: String) {      

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
               println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println("error not nil::::::")
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
        
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["variants"] as NSArray
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            
            self.jsonTable = results
            self.productView!.reloadData()
           })
     })
```

But I am getting this error:

> `error not nil::::::`
>
> `The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1002.)`

I am able to get the JSON in the browser through the same URL.
I have tried reading [this Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html), but I can't get the description.

What does this error code mean?

Comment: -1002 is NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL, which indicates that your `urlPath` is wrong.

Comment: NSURLErrorDomain error -1002 means `NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL` or `kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL`. It is most likely that your url string lacks 'http://' in the url prefix.

Comment: @AsifAsif : But where do you get the description of these error codes?

Comment: @sasquatch: you can find the list here (switch `Language` to `Obj-C`): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`NSURLErrorDomain error -1002` means `NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL` or `kCFURLErrorUnsupportedURL`. It indicates that a bad URL was provided, in most cases, missing `http://` from the URL prefix.

The list of all `NSURLErrorDomain` codes can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, one of the reasons why this could happen is,

You might have set the **Allow Arbitrary Loads** to `false` in your Info.plist and the URL you are trying to load is not on a secured server.

The solution to this is either set it to `true`, or move to a secure connection i.e `https://`.

Hope it helps someone. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue and found that **key** parameter was missing from URL. You need to set **Google map key** value for key parameter in URL you are using to make request. This can also occur if you are missing other keys.